# Laravel Session Permission Denied issue on Mac

Tags: macos, laravel, session, permissions

Recently switched to mac, and I was having an issue when trying login into the laravel based app:

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
file_put_contents(/var/www/webapp/storage/framework/sessions
/5d81ef5668e268c670c6eec83dccf0ba0d532d7c): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Comment: You should add it as an actual answer and market it as the accepted answer so others can easily see this has already been answered.

Answer (score 4):

Hope its useful, as I managed to resolve the issue after running following on console/terminal:

```
chmod -R 777 storage/
sudo chmod -R +ai "everyone allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown" storage/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I found the solution below.

1. Go to your project root folder via Finder where you keep all your projects and right click on it.
2. Then, click on "Get Info" and you will see the pop-up window.
3. At bottom-right of the window, there is 'Lock' icon, click on it to Unlock it.
4. Next, select the 'Read and Write' (if it was readonly) privilege for 'staff' name.
5. Afterwards, keep select the 'staff' name, then click to 'Setting' icon next to +/- signs, and select 'Apply to enclosed items...'.
6. Finally, click the 'Lock' icon to make it locked once you completed above steps[image]

Then, your project file has full permission for Read/write and you don't need to `chmod 777` all time.
.

Answer (score 0):

For me using laravel 4.2, the solution was to run the command `sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage` it is better to find where the storage folder is then run the command by using the appropriate location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope its useful, as I managed to resolve the issue after running following on console/terminal:

Simply open your terminal, to resolve the issue after running following on console/terminal:

chmod -R 777 /